# omit delimiting characters from a result of a match regex

Tags: javascript

I have this string and I Want to extract strings that are between ^ but without the ^ itself in javascript:

```
 const input = "^k^ 989 ^s^"

 var ptrn = /\^(.*?)\^/mg;
 var results = input.match(ptrn);
 console.log(results)  ==> ["^k^" , "^s^]
```

the following with exec has a different result but I prefer the match method than the loop of exec to get all matches

```
 let results = ptrn.exec(input);
 console.log(results) ==> ["^k^", "k"]
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)?

Answer (score 0):

as another way, you can use split to achieve that.

```
const input = "^k^ 989 ^s^";
const results = input
  .split('^')
  .filter((_, index) => index % 2 === 1);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: i cant compile it now but will see why later on. thanks Kavian

Comment: so please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped :)